# css3 navigation menu hover state issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

This is my code what i have tried:

```
 body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 990px;
}
.nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
.nav ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
.nav ul li {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
}
.nav ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #069;
}
```

This is JSFiddle:

[jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/1](http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/1/)

May i know how to set full width of navigation? when resize the window, navigation bar should be full width, and lists are should be center. how to fix this?

I need to add code for getting output like this(as i marked what i want):

[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site

Comment: sorry @ChamikaSandamal: I searched in google, still didn't get solution for this, so only asking with help of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/3/)

I have used.

`display: table` and `display: table-cell`

and **no need of js for this**

Comment: Thanks, but yours answer not exactly, what i need.

Answer (score 0):

i have added `display: inline-flex;` this property in `.nav`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/2/)

Comment: In sub menu look like, my posted image above.

Comment: http://themedemos.dottoro.com/features/menu/horizontal-submenu/ refer this you may get some help.